# How to dynamically associate html content through Onet.xml in Content Editor WebPart?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

We are using SharePoint Foundation 2010

We have a custom site definition where in Onet.xml we have placed a Content Editor Web Part  on a Custom ASPX page having encoded html content in it just like how it is described in [this](http://blogs.edwardwilde.com/2009/11/16/how-to-add-a-content-editor-web-contenteditorwebpart-part-via-your-onet-xml-or-elements-manifest/) article.

Issue with this approach is that following this approach makes the HTML content static and can not be dynamically changed for each user.

Is there a way i can make Onet.xml refer an HTML file from a SharePoint folder e.g. Layouts, so that when content gets changed in the HTML file, it gets reflected for each user on their custom page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, I think I will be using Page Viewer Web Part instead of Content Editor Web Part which would make my life simpler. I would add an html file path from say Layouts folder and refer it in my Page Viewer Web Part. This way my content would remain dynamic.